# How to end the while loop until the moment there is no match data in the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to generate a short link and avoid the same pattern. My pseudo code is like this:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  to generate a short link
  while(if there is the same short link in database ) {
    to generate a short links (until no match in database)
  }
  save the short link to database
  res.render
});
```

However, how to jump out the while loop successfully?

```
const errors = validationResult(req)
  const baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/"
  let randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5)
  let originalLink = req.body.originalLink
  let shortURL = ''
  shortURL = baseURL + randomString

  Link.find({ "shortLink": shortURL }, (err, results) => {
      if (err) return err
      // validate repeat shortURL
      while (results.length > 0) {
        randomString = Math.random().toString(36).slice(4, 9)
        shortURL = baseURL + randomString
        Link.find({ "shortLink": shortURL }, (err, results))
      }

      Link.find({ "link": originalLink }, (err, results) => {
        const link = Link({
          link: originalLink,
          shortLink: shortURL
        })
        if (err) return err
        // validate repeat original Link
        if (results.length > 0) {
          shortURL = results[0]['shortLink']
          res.render('result', { shortURL: shortURL, originalLink: originalLink })
        } else {
          link.save(err => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            res.render('result', { shortURL: shortURL, originalLink: originalLink })
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

The short links will be generated until no match in the database.

Comment: What do you think this is doing: `Link.find({ "shortLink": shortURL }, (err, results))`?  You're supposed to be passing a callback function there.  That code does absolutely nothing useful and provides you no result.

Comment: Hint: You can only use a `while()` loop with an asynchronous operation if you use promises and `async/await` so you can `await` the database `.find()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your hint. It is really useful. "Async/await" method is what I need right now.